# Why does my custom DataGridViewEditingControl never receive KeyDown events for the Enter Key?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a custom DataGridView editing control which uses the Enter key for some of its functionality. It implements the `IDataGridViewEditingControl` interface method '`EditingControlWantsInputKey' using the following code:

```
public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys keyData, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
{
    switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
        case Keys.Right:
        case Keys.Up:
        case Keys.Down:
        case Keys.Home:
        case Keys.End:
        case Keys.Enter:
        case Keys.Delete:
            return true;

        default:
            return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
    }
}
```

However, it never receives the KeyDown event for the Enter key. I've put a conditional breakpoint in the `EditingControlWantsInputKey` method to see if the data grid view was ever calling it to find out if I want to respond to the Enter key only to find out it is never called.

In my editing control, I overrode the `ProcessCmdKey` method to see if the underlying `Message` was being sent to the control with the following code.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if ((msg.Msg == User32.WM_KEYDOWN) &&
        ((Keys)msg.WParam == Keys.Enter))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GOT HERE");
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

It is in-fact getting the message, but it is never sent to the `OnKeyDown` method.

At one point I thought the `DataGridView` may have been registering a `IMessageFilter` to handle the key itself, but if that were the case, the control would get the call to `ProcessCmdKey` (I checked this myself by adding my own `IMessageFilter`).

Does anyone know what the DataGridView is doing to prevent my custom editing control from getting the call to `OnKeyDown` and if there is a way to change that behavior?

The only thing I can think of is to handle the routing of the message myself from the `ProcessCmdKey` method, but that just feel hackish.

[Edit]

To answer King King's comment:

The editing control is a custom subclass of a `TextBox`. The custom subclass works simply by adding more advanced auto-complete functionality (better than the built in support for a `TextBox`). The custom text box uses the KeyDown event to know when the user wants to select a suggested auto-complete item. It is used several other places in the application has been used in production code for months (so I'm pretty confident that it is not the culprit).

[Edit - with sample code]

I've constructed a minimal program which seems to show this happening. Create a new WinForms project and put a DataGridView in the Form. Sorry for the wall of code, but this is bare minimal needed to see the effect.

If ran, you'll notice that `EditingControlWantsInputKey` will never get called for the `CustomEditingControl` when the key code is Enter, `OnKeyDown` won't be called, but `ProcessCmdKey` will be called.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += this.DataGridView_EditingControlShowing;
    }

    private void DataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Must remove first to avoid adding the same event handler twice.
        e.Control.KeyDown -= this.EditingControl_KeyDown;
        e.Control.KeyDown += this.EditingControl_KeyDown;
    }

    private void EditingControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
    }
}

public class CustomEditingControl : DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl
{
    public override bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys keyData, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        if ((Keys.KeyCode & keyData) == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EditingControlWantsInputKey: Enter");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EditingControlWantsInputKey: Other");
        }

        return base.EditingControlWantsInputKey(keyData, dataGridViewWantsInputKey);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

        if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) &&
            ((Keys)msg.WParam == Keys.Enter))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessCmdKey: Enter");
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnKeyDown: Enter");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnKeyDown: Other");
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}

public class CustomDataGridViewTextBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomEditingControl);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomDataGridViewColumn : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    public CustomDataGridViewColumn()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new CustomDataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    }
}
```

[Edit - with more findings]

I added as much logging as I could to the message chain. For a normal text box, pressing the Enter key results in a message trail like the following:

```
PreFilterMessage: Return
PreProcessMessage: Return
ProcessCmdKey: Return
WndProc: Return
ProcessKeyPreview: Return
OnKeyDown: Return
```

For the editing control pressing the '1' key (for example) yields the following trail:

```
PreFilterMessage: D1
PreProcessMessage: D1
ProcessCmdKey: D1
WndProc: D1
EditingControlWantsInputKey: D1
ProcessKeyPreview: D1
OnKeyDown: D1
EditingControl_KeyDown: D1 (This is from the hooked up event handler)
```

For the editing control pressing the 'Enter' key yields the following trail

```
PreFilterMessage: Return
PreProcessMessage: Return
ProcessCmdKey: Return
```

So something (presumably the DataGridView) is capturing the message between the `ProcessCmdKey` and the `WndProc` methods.

Comment: Do you mean that just happens to `Enter` key only and other keys are received OK?

Comment: What is the base class your `DataGridViewEditingControl` inherits? Maybe that base class overrides and filters out the `Enter` key down event.

Comment: @KingKing All other keys work fine.

Comment: @KingKing Added an edit to the question to answer your second comment.

Comment: I've found that this also happens to the default EditingControl, the `Enter` key seems to be swallowed by the DataGridView. I think you may have to catch the Enter key in the `ProcessCmdKey` as you tried.

Comment: I'm working through things a little deeper to see if I can nail down exactly where things go weird. The message is sent to all registered message filters and the the `ProcessCmdKey` function, but doesn't seem to hit the `WndProc` method, which I thought was odd because I thought it would hit `WndProc` before `ProcessCmdKey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging, I've found a solution that seems the least bit hackish.

Create a new `IMessageFilter`, I ended up with something of the following:

```
private sealed class RouteKeyDownMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    private readonly Control mControl;
    private readonly Keys mKey;

    public RouteKeyDownMessageFilter(Control control, Keys key)
    {
        this.mControl = control;
        this.mKey = (Keys.KeyCode & key);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if ((m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) &&
            (m.HWnd == this.mControl.Handle) &&
            (((Keys)m.WParam & Keys.KeyCode) == this.mKey))
        {
            SendMessage(m.HWnd, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
}
```

Then, in the class implementing the `IDataGridViewEditingControl` interface, I added this additional logic to the `EditingControlDataGridView` property to register/unregister the message filter.

```
public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
{
    get { return this.mEditingControlDataGridView; }
    set
    {
        if (this.mEditingControlDataGridView != null)
        {
            this.mEditingControlDataGridView.Disposed -= this.EditingControlDataGridView_Disposed;

            Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this.mCurrentMessageFilter);
            this.mCurrentMessageFilter = null;
        }

        this.mEditingControlDataGridView = value;

        if (this.mEditingControlDataGridView != null)
        {
            this.mCurrentMessageFilter = new RouteKeyDownMessageFilter(this, Keys.Return);
            Application.AddMessageFilter(this.mCurrentMessageFilter);

            this.mEditingControlDataGridView.Disposed += this.EditingControlDataGridView_Disposed;
        }
    }
}

private void EditingControlDataGridView_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.mCurrentMessageFilter != null)
    {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this.mCurrentMessageFilter);
    }
}
```

So all this does it ensure the message filter is in place whenever the editing control has a data grid view assigned to it. It also registers an event handler for the data grid view's `Dispose` event to make sure we unregister the message filter when the data grid view gets cleaned up.

The message filter itself just takes a control and a trigger key and re-routes the message when it gets the message for the given control. It is important to reference the `Control` and not the `Handle` of the `Control` because the `Handle` may change in the `Control`'s lifetime.

I'm a little baffled that re-sending the message does the trick, but when this in place (and the appropriate logging) I get the following message chaining:

```
RoutingMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage: Return
RoutingMessageFilter, Routing Message.
WndProc: Return
EditingControlWantsInputKey: Return
PreProcessMessage: Return
ProcessCmdKey: Return
WndProc: Return
OnKeyDown: Return
EditingControl_KeyDown: Return
```

The only odd thing about this message flow is that `WndProc` is called twice. I'm not sure why this happened, but it doesn't seem to have any ill side-effects. More importantly, the `EditingControlWantsInputKey` now properly gets called along with the `OnKeyDown` method in the editing control.

Comment: I've managed to make it work using your technique, the issue I had was that the Handle that get the Enter key wasn't necessary the control that have the filter... it's a complete control that popup another ctrl. But thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey

See the reference .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.processdialogkey(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't think it helps, you should try yourself and make sure it works first before answering. The OP wants the EditingControl to be able to receive the `Enter` key press event and handle everything in a `KeyPress` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the OnPreviewKeyDown did the trick for me...

Protected Overrides Sub OnPreviewKeyDown(e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
        'MyBase.OnPreviewKeyDown(e)
        e.IsInputKey = True
End Sub

Answer (score -1):

To achieve that a user control (e.g. derived from Panel) receives KeyDown messages it must first have the keyboard focus.

This can be done with a few lines. The following code focuses the control by using the Tab key or the mouse.

```
public Constructor() 
{
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
    TabStop = true;
}
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    Focus();
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

Comment: It feels like you did not fully read the question. The issue deals with only the Enter key and only in the context of a DataGridView as an editing control. It is not this simple.

Comment: Ok. maybe in your special case it was like that. But your question has a high ranking in Google for all those who are searching for a Control that does not receive keyboard events. People are not only interested in YOUR SPECIFIC problem. My answer is surely more useful for the majority of people coming here from Google than your answer. Don't be so selfish to think only in yourself!